# Nickel Chromium Wire for high temperatures

Tags: heating-systems

I've been trying for months to find a way to heat moving air inside a tube to high temperatures.  The closest to success I ever had was using an element from a heat gun. It would achieve the desired temperature but over time would burn out.

This has led me to believe making my own coil is probably the best approach.

**Parameters**

So my desired temperature in the tube is about 450 degrees F with around 400 CFM going through it. At 1500 watts of power,  what diameter and length nickel chromium wire would I need for this?

Comment: Something like this? https://www.omega.com/en-us/industrial-heaters/duct-and-enclosure-heaters/duct-heaters/p/AHF-HEATER

Comment: @Eric Shain yes just like that except I'm using 2 inch instead

Comment: The mounting flange is 4”. The tube is 2 3/8”. Maybe just call Omega and see if the have something closer to what you need. They’re a good company.

Comment: If NiChrome "burned out" you were not moving enough air past it to remove heat and allowed it to get too hot.

Comment: @EricShain I actually ordered one from them, snipped the flange to my size, will be trying soon but seems promising. Thank you for recommending that company.

Comment: The key phrase you're probably missing in your searches is "watt density". Heater manufacturers rate their various materials of construction based on watt density for different flow rates of different fluids. Try this from an arbitrary manufacturer: http://www.chromalox.com/catalog/resources/technical-information/Heat-Loss-Calculations-and-Heater-Selection-Watt-Density.pdf Some, like Leister, specialize in air blowers in particular.

Comment: At some point it might be worth considering if the wire burning through should be treated as a malfunction or as depletion of a consumable like replacing worn tires of a car, or exchanging oil.

Answer (score 1):

Nichrome wire *is* the correct material to use for this. That's almost certainly what the heat gun element is made from anyway.

You may be able to increase the longevity by using more nichrome wire for the same power, thus reducing the wire temperature. You will need to increase the wire diameter, or run strands in parallel to maintain the same wattage.

Due to the popularity of vaping, assortments of nichrome wire in various gauges can be purchased on amazon and ebay.

Answer (score 0):

Nichrome , very similar to Inconel 600 and 601 : Is/are the standards ,actually  about the only choice ; some manufacturers may put different names on the same stuff.